# How to hide the error message until next form submission

Tags: angular

userExists is fetched from the server so it needs a submission. If the error message is displayed and if the user types something inside the email input field then its marked as untouched and the error message goes away but as soon as the user moves the focus out of the input field the message is displayed again. How to make it disappear once the user inputs something until the next submission.

```
<form [formGroup]="resetPasswordForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div *ngIf="submitted && resetPasswordForm.controls.email.touched ">
       <input (input)="emailExistsHide()" formControlName="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Enter your Registered email id *"/>
       <div *ngIf="userExists==false">User with that email does not exist</div>  
    </div>

 <button type="submit" class="log-button log-button1">Reset Password</button>
</form>
```

Typescript

```
emailExistsHide() {
  this.resetPasswordForm.controls.email.markAsUntouched();
}
```

Comment: What about resetting the variable submitted ? Shouldn't that be done in your method? Also, wouldn't *ngIf="!userExists" be better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps add `this.userExists=true;`inside `emailExistsHide()`. Since you haven't given code for onSubmit() it's hard to tell if this will wash..

Comment: it has nothing but  `onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    if (this.resetPasswordForm.invalid) {
      return;
  }`  Well, this seems to be the only way to do it. I was looking for a cleaner way coz if I change the value of userExisits like that I wont be able to use it in other parts of the code as it will wrongly trigger true.

Comment: Then use a second flag for the *ngIf - if you want some sort of model based property to control logic. Call it displayUserExistsWarning perhaps?